# How do I remove objects on stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a game of enemies in an array coming down on the screen. When the user hits the pause button they are taken to a different screen (Pause Screen). This function initiates:

```
function PauseGame():void
{

    if (gameState == STATE_PLAY_GAME)
    {
        Rchannel.stop();
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopR);
        for each(var tempEnemy:MovieClip in enemies)
        {
         tempEnemy.visible = false;
        }
}
}
```

It freezes the enemies and hides them. There is also a restart button. If the user clicks the restart button, the enemies that were on the stage are not there, but they are invisibly moving to deduct the player's health. This is the restart function:

```
function resetRclick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Rchannel = rSound.play(0,9999);
    score = 0
    roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
    lives = 3
    roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
    level = 1
    roachLevel.level_txt.text = String(level);
    roachLevel.gotoAndPlay(1);
    roachLevel.visible = true;
    Menu_mc.visible = false;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoopR);

}
```

How can I remove the enemies that are on the screen at the time, while not hindering the set up of the game?

Comment: You have to make them visible again, right ? Why not just do that ?

Comment: Because I want the level to be cleared. Like a restart. Nothing on the screen from the previous play time.

Comment: so why not just remove them ? you addChild to put them on the display list, right ? removeChild removes them.

Answer (score 0):

Without calling `removeChild` for the enemies and the 'old' level you're simply drawing over the top (not good!).

You'll want to call `removeChild` for every enemy (even though they're all not visible) and also clear out your `enemies` list (assuming you're following conventional game logic whereby every enemy in the enemies list is updated).

If you added all of the enemies to the roachLevel movieclip your code would look similar to:

```
while(enemies.length > 0)
{
    roachLevel.removeChild(enemies[0])
    enemies.splice(0,1);
}
```

*Note: I've not written any AS3 for a while so syntax may not be 100% correct, sorry.

Comment: If 'enemies' in an Array the last line of this suggested code should be something like 'enemies[0].remove();' where remove is a method on whatever Class the enemies are. The remove method should remove any event listeners internal to the enemy. You might want to add a line, that .splices out the enemy at index 0. Then, when you .push new enemies onto your Array, you're starting with an empty Array.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to remove these children would be to place them inside a movieclip container. For example:

```
var container:MovieClip;
container = new MovieClip();
addChild(container);

//Add enemies inside container
container.addChild(enemy);
```

Then when you need to delete them:

```
removeChild(container);
```

And they're all gone! I think the syntax on all of those is correct. I'll leave it up to you to decide how best to implement this if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

another way that would match your code more would be:

```
for each(var tempEnemy:MovieClip in enemies)
{
    tempEnemy.visible = false;
    removeChild(tempEnemy);
}
enemies = [];
```